# Changing cranksets

Tags: road

Ive done hardly any cycling and know virtually nothing about road bikes, but Ive bought a second hand Avanti Vervace with the intention of doing the around Lake Taupo ride (160km). Apparently the crankset is worn and Ive seen a new Shimano Taigra crankset for sale on trademe. Can i simply swap the cranksets over? Any advice would be hugely appreciated. Working on a limited budget here. Cheers

Comment: Why not just change the chainrings?

Comment: Can you pop into the [chat] room to discuss further?

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I obviously need to spend a little time on the internet learning about my bike and the various components and then I can ask questions with a bit more knowledge of what Im talking about. Cheers for the help. Thankfully the wheels turn but I may need to spend some money on it according to a local bike shop.

Answer (score 1):

A Crankset is both crank arms, a spider, the chain ring or rings, and the bolts holding the chainrings to the spider.

If the BCD (Bolt Circle Diameter) is the same, then you can simply swap the chainrings over.

Swapping the crankset means you need more specialised tools, and the bottom bracket standards may have changed over time meaning they're possibly incompatible.

Either way you might need to adjust your Front Derailleur, and depending on what the donor bike was, you might find the new chainrings are narrower (10 and 11 speed maybe) whereas your bike looks like a 2004-2009 brand and might be 8 or 9 speed, therefore a slightly wider chain.